to solve just any problem
a. You can't program this computer to solve any problem.
b. You can't program this computer to solve just any problem.
Is there a difference between the meanings of (a) and (b)?
Can (a) ever be used instead of (b) (probably with heavy emphasis on 'any)?
Isn't (b) ambiguous? Can't it have two meanings:

You can program this computer to solve certain problems, but not just any problem.

You can't program this computer in such a manner that it will be able to solve just any problem.


Many thanks.

It seems to me your "meanings 1 and 2" are the same thing, stated differently. At least in this context. I mean, meaning 2 could technically be true if the computer couldn't be programmed at all... but this sentence would be unlikely in this case, and intentionally misleading.

Thank you all very much. You are correct, Andy. I messed up. Sorry.

There is a very big difference.

"not any problem" would mean no problems at all. Your sentence would therefore mean that the computer was useless, because it could not solve any problem.

"not just any problem" means some specific problems. So this would mean that the computer could solve certain specific kinds of problems, but not others.


We commonly use "not just any" to make something sound exclusive in an elevated, privileged sense - for example, if a car sales business said "we don't sell just any car" the inference would be that they are selective in the cars they sell; that they sell very special cars.

Yes, and often we use 'not... just any' to correct unrealistic expectations.

The first sentence is ambiguous. If you say, "You can't use this computer to solve any problem", that might mean that the computer is useless, that it cannot be used to solve any problem at all. Or it might simply mean that it is limited. It can't solve any problem that you can possibly imagine, but it can solve some problems.
The second sentence makes clear that you mean the second idea. The computer can solve some problems, but not all problems.
